USB-C Alternate Mode - ensure no activity on TX / RX pins during enumeration?
I am working on a project that will consist of a USB-C host and device. The idea is that the host will use the alternate mode pins of a USB-C connector to drive analog signals to peripherals on the device. To ensure that the user accidentally plugging the device into a computer (or any other USB port) does not cause any problems, I am trying to make sure I use the proper enumeration and negotiation protocols.
During enumeration / negotiation, how can I ensure that there is no activity on the TX/RX pair pins of the USB-C connector?
Any signals on the TX/RX pins can damage the analog peripherals on the device side. When not being driven by the host device, the TX/RX pins must be kept at the same potential (no DC bias) to avoid damage.
My original idea was to use transistors or MOSFETs to pull the TX/RX pins to either V+ or GND until alternate mode negotiation is done. This would protect the analog peripherals, but I'm not sure if it would damage any standard USB-C port on a computer (or mess up the enumeration process). An ideal solution would be to use an analog switch IC to disconnect the pins from the analog peripherals, but space is very limited and a solution size involving minimal components is preferred.

What do you mean under "the alternate mode pins of a USB-C connector"?  USB-C connector has very well defined pin names, and I am not aware of any "alternate mode pins". Could you please use the established names of the USB-C connector?

@Ale..chenski Seriously you are unaware? USB-C can be used for any purpose. You can e.g. use the connector for a passive headset adapter or debug adapter as long as your devices can recognize each other and change the function of pins accordingly. Just like sending DisplayPort in Alt-Mode over Type-C over the data pairs. It's also used for HDMI alt mode, Thunderbolt, etc.

The next question for OP is, how do you intend to negotiate the custom usage, and does the device even need to connect to standard USB-C devices, and if yes, for what purpose?

@Justme, seriously? You didn't get the meaning of my comment? I am well aware of multiple use and re-use of standard TYPE-C pins that can perform in DIFFERENT ALTERNATIVE FUNCTIONS. But there is no special "alternate mode pins" that OP seems to want to re-use for some nonstandard analog channels. If the OP is concerned about signaling under accidental plug into a live USB host/device, he/she needs to specify precisely which standard pins he wants to reuse and protect.

@Ale..chenski Oh OK sorry, I simply interpreted from the question that the pins are used in alt mode, and I should have see your comment meaning the same but just requesting to be clear on the terms pin vs function.

The usual solution is to keep the pins disconnected or undriven until the usage for the pins is known.
If you use them for sensititive analog inputs/outputs then both devices must have analog muxes that only connect the signals to the pins when negotiated.
